# Rosserial on ARM-32 (S32K14X family) works?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ethernet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have to define which MCU my team will use to communicate via ROSserial (TCP/IP) between a computer and a hardware I/O board (that we need to develop WITH THIS MCU or can be other - depends of the answers). We came across with S32K148 MCU (datasheet: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/S32K-DS.pdf) and we thought this MCU will be great to use due the support on ethernet, some other libraries, industrial protocols support and great amount of I/O. Question is: the rosserial-mbed support this type of MCU? Anyone already tested it? In ROS support I can't find the hardware compatibility, only say that works on ARM-32 Cortex-M family (S32K148 is a Cortex-M4F). Need help to define this. Plz.

Sry for my bad english..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318249/rosserial-on-arm-32-(s32k14x-family)-works?/) by [Hyperion](https://answers.ros.org/users/40208/hyperion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look at README in ROS Serial MBED git repository it says that LPC1768, KL25Z, and NUCLEO F401RE are supported over the UART.

Personally, I am thinking it would be faster to implement a simple message passing protocol myself.  ROS Serial is a very heavy weight solution

another option is  [ros_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite)

---

Originally posted by [chrisalbertson](https://answers.ros.org/users/21344/chrisalbertson/) with karma: 136 on 2019-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hyperion](https://answers.ros.org/users/40208/hyperion/) on 2020-01-30**:
thanks, i'll try